# Perform query calculations on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structures

**table sales:**

```
ID, SALES_DATE
```

**table sales_payment:**

```
ID, SALES_ID, PAYMENT_DATE
```

Where `SALES_ID` is a foreign key to sales table `ID`. table sales_payment has a *many to one relationship* to table sales where one sales can have multiple payments (e.g. a payment today and another payment after five days)

I want a query that can calculate the average overall payment days for each sales taking the maximum number of days to fully pay the sales.

**Considering this scenario:**

the first sales is made in `2014-01-01`, and its payments are in

- `2014-01-02`
- `2014-01-05`

(days to pay for the sales are **`4`** days)

the second sales is made in `2014-01-03`, and its payments are in :

- `2014-01-03`
- `2014-01-04`
- `2014-01-05`
- `2014-01-11`

(days to pay for the sales are `8` days)

so the return average is the average of the days of each sales to be fully paid :

`(4+8)/2 = (6 days)`

I have made this on programming level but it is taking too much time to retrieve data and perform loops for thousands of raws. How this can be achieved on sql level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you first want to calculate the payment days for each sale.  Then take the average of this value:

```
select avg(paymentdays)
from (select sp.sales_id, (datediff(max(sp.payment_date), min(sp.payment_date)) + 1) as paymentdays
      from sales_payment sp
      group by sp.sales_id
     ) sp;
```

Comment: @fareed . . . I had the arguments in the wrong order, but that would have just made the results negative.  Are you sure you have `group by sp.sales_id` and not `group by sp.id`?

Comment: Now it works fine, yeah it was giving a negative result. Thanks :))

Comment: sorry it was some typos for me that resulted in wrong results. After altering it was giving negative results. After your edit it is giving the right value

Comment: @fareed . . . I'm curious why you unaccepted this answer.  The answer you accepted groups twice by `sales_id` -- meaning that the second aggregation is doing nothing.  It is not producing the average value (as described in your question).  It is just producing a single value for each `sales_id`.

Comment: After implemntation I found some logical errors in your answer, the second answer was producing more accurate results but now also calculates some inaccurate results as well, I don't know where is this coming from. I will investigate more and get back to you. Thanks for your concern and sorry for that

Comment: I found the problem. Ok aparently it is calculating the difference between the first payment and the last payment where I wanted the difference between the sales date and the last payment. so this has solved the problem (datediff(max(sp.payment_date), min(s.sales_date) from sales_payment sp, sales s

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem (If I have understand it, you want to start counting days since `sales.sales_date` ):

```
select sp.sales_id, avg(paymentdays)
from (select sp.sales_id, ( max(sp.payment_date) - min(s.sales_date) ) as paymentdays
      from sales_payment sp, sales s
    where sp.sales_id = s.id
      group by sp.sales_id
     ) sp
     group by sp.sales_id
```